# How to backup my symphony v50 rom without pc?

Tags: backup

I have a symphony v50 mobile. I can not go to
recovery mod when my phone was switched off.I was trying to go recovery mood by hold click
volume up+power buttons. But not go to
recovery. It goes to phone test function.
When I go to make a backup of my current rom
with rom manager i did not get the backup
option in the recovery mood. May I change the cwm recovery? If the
ans is yes please tell me how. Else how I can
make a backup of my current rom?

Answer (score 0):

flash stock ROM that will fix ur v50 my phone is also v50

Comment: Sorry, but how does that create a backup? OK, OP wasn't clear what the backup should be used for – but I'd expect it's for extracting/saving some data stored on the device.